# How to write test cases in Jest for login page

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

The following code is what I have written in order for the Admin to log in to the system. I am now trying to carry out unit testing and have to test the ValidateLogin for admin in particular. I have chosen jest to do that.

I created a test file:

```
const LoginController = reqire('./LoginController')
test('login to the system', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
})
```

Instead of checking for true to be true. I want to check for the username and password to be true. Please explain how should I do it.

Following is the code for login:

```
class User {
    username;
    password;
    email;
    firstName;
    lastName;
    roleName;

    constructor(username,password,email,firstName, lastName, roleName){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    getlogininfo(username, password, callback) {       
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM User Where username = '" + username + 
            "' AND password = '" + password + "'";
        var Username;
        var dataRes;

        con.query(sql, function(err, results){
            if (err){ 
                throw err;
            }

            if(results.length>0) { //result is not empty
                Username = results[0].username;  // Scope is larger than function
                dataRes = {
                    username: results[0].username,
                    firstName: results[0].firstName,
                    lastName: results[0].lastName,
                    roleName: results[0].roleName
                }
                return callback(dataRes);
            } else {
                return callback(false);
            }
        })
    }
}

exports.User = User
```

```
class LoginController {
 
    ValidateLogin(req, res) {   
        let user = new User(); 

        var dataRes;
        var username = req.body.username
        var password = req.body.password

        console.log(username + "kekw" + password); 
        
        user.getlogininfo(username, password, function(result){
            if(result) { 
                dataRes = result;
                var session;

                // Login endpoint               
                if(dataRes.roleName == "useradmin") {
                    console.log("Call User Admin Dashboard");
                    res.redirect("/UserAdmin");
                }
                else if(dataRes.roleName == "manager") {
                    console.log("Call Manager Dashboard");
                    res.redirect("/Manager");
                }
                else if(dataRes.roleName == "staff") {
                    console.log("Called Staff Dashboard");
                    res.redirect('/Staff');
                }
                else if(dataRes.roleName == "customer") {
                    console.log("Called Customer Dashboard");
                    res.redirect('/Customer');
                }
                /*
                else if(dataRes.role == "Pharmacist") {
                    console.log("Called Pharmacist home");
                    res.redirect('/PharmacistHome');
                }
                else if(dataRes.role == "Patient") {
                    console.log("Called Patient home");
                    res.redirect('/PatientHome');
                }*/                
            }
            else {
                req.flash('message', 'Wrong Username or Password!')
                res.redirect("/?error=true");
                return false;
            }
        });        
    }    
}

//module.exports = LoginController;
exports.LoginController = LoginController;
```

I want to write test cases for username and password for the useradmin login. How do I do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please send your complete error code? It would be very helpful to get a solution. Although i think it could be an error with ES6 modules. Check if you have `"type": "module"` in your package.json. If that's the case you have to import your LoginController with `import * from './LoginController'`

You wrote „require“ wrong:
Like this: `const LoginController = reqire('./LoginController');`

Comment: Have added the error message in the question. I only have type in repository which is "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/technext/feane.git"
  } in the package.json file.

Comment: you wrote "require" wrong. It means require() and not reqire. But sorry that I didn't see your Error Message

Comment: GREAT! the test case passed. Can you please tell me how can I make test cases for username and password now?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with test cases? What do you want to test?

Comment: I want to test for login using username and password as input and true as the output of the test case.

Comment: @Baumistlustig - Please update your answer with the fix you have identified and explained in the comment above

Comment: Instead of checking for true to be true. I want to check for the username and password to be true. Please explain how should I do it.